# Is this the most effective way to check that there are values returned?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is this is most effective way to check `fetch_assoc();`?

```
$something_row = $something->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); // get result 

if($something > 1){
 // DO THIS
}else{
 // DO THIS
}
```

I don't know of any other way but this just doesn't feel like the best way to check if there are values returned.

Why I use 1 is because if you say if ($something == true){} sometimes the fetch_assoc(); will return -1 and that will consider as a true value for the if statement.

Comment: Is `fetch_Assoc()` your own function or a predefined function like `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`? Because that function does not return `-1`. What are you trying to check anyway and why?

Comment: it is the ```mysqli_result::fetch_assoc``` i read somewhere on stackoverflow that it can return -1 idk if that was true or not but i used one because when i use true it will return that the value was true even though it was not

Comment: i am trying to check if there was data from the sql query and if there was then display it else say there was no data in the database @Progman

Comment: why do you feel that?

Comment: fetch_assoc(); never returns  -1, you are confusing it with something else

Comment: @Progman what's the point in making an extra function call? Yes he can. But why?

Answer (score 1):

[`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) will always return either an array with data or `null`. Due to [PHP's type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), an array filled with data is a "truey" value and null is "falsey". Which means you can safely use the result in the `if` operator

You don't have to add anything special. Simply put the resulting value in a conditional operator.

```
$something_row = $something->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); // get result 

if($something_row) {
    echo 'Yes, we have some values';
} else {
    echo 'Nothing returned';
}
```

The same applies to [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), but this function will always return an array, no matter if any rows were found or not. But an empty array is again equal to `false` and therefore the result can be used in the condition as well.

Answer (score -2):

Does it have to be a boolean? I think you're looking for [$results->num_rows;](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
$number_or_results = $results->num_rows;
if($number_or_results){
 // DO STUFF WITH RESULTS
}
else{
 // TELL USER THERE'S NO DATA
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that using num_rows for pagination is a true **disaster**. Imagine there is a million of rows and you select them all only to tell the number?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Post your solution

Comment: Why should I post a solution if it's already posted? Also, what does it to do with the problems I mentioned?

Comment: Your statement makes no sense. Pagination literally means "when results are limited" (to one page at a time). Fetching all rows is not even nearly "common" but rather a disaster that would cause memory errors. Please avoid giving a bad advise.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that's right. Flew right by past me.

Comment: While it's true that `num_rows` can be used to find out if there were any rows fetched from the query, but using it is definitely a code smell. If you are fetching the data, then you have the data itself to determine if you have results or not. If you are not going to fetch the data then what was the point in making the query at all. This means that calling `num_rows` function is never needed.

Comment: Pagination omitted. For what questioner is asking, $results->num_rows; is exactly what's needed to check if there's results so I will leave the answer and I believe it it's better than using result array to check

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's better to make an extra function call? Please note that OP already called `fetch_assoc()` and they want to know if it returned any data or not.